# Hooks for trashing, deleting, saving, restoring custom post type

Tags: hooks

I need some hooks especially for trashing and untrashing custom post types. However the hooks are not so clear in this case.

For example, to run a function on trash, I can use

```
     add_action('wp_trash_post','my_function');
```

However there doesn't seem to be any other action specific to custom post types. So how would I execute my function on trashing of a custom post type?

Answer (score 8):

Two action hooks run when a post is trashed wp_trash_post before the post is trashed and trashed_post afterwards.  These run for any post type including attachments.

See wp-includes/post.php

If you want to limit your function to a specific post type you need to run a check in you callback function.

```
function my_trash_action( $post_id ) {
   if ( 'custom_post_type' != get_post_type( $post_id )
       return;
     //Do Stuff....
}
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'my_trash_action' );
```

Comment: So in my function then how can I check that my custom post type was deleted, not any other post type?

Comment: Also can I use the hook trash_my_cpt that would fire only for my custom post type? Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions and https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L3125

Comment: I think you can use wp_trash_mycpt